# Set YARN application ID Spark app

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I found the way to get applicationId from SparkContext ,

```
sc.applicationId
```

but is there way I can setup this too ? The app needs to be submitted using yarn-cluster . So I need to stop it when needed using applicationId.

Does this applicationId same as the applicationId in YARN ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the SparkContext application ID will refer to the same YARN application ID when the application is submitted in yarn-cluster mode.

```
sc.applicationId
```

[See the Spark Scala API docs.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)